# Using '_all_docs?keys=' to query db and specifying which fields to return

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'd like to do a bulk query to `cloudant` db.

By supplying a list of `_id`s (primary key), and have db return any documents with matching `_id`s.

This is working as shown below. But I'd like to return `_id`, `_rev` and `field_name` also. Is there a way to do this without using `include_docs=true`?

Request:

```
http://{db-host}/{db-name}/_all_docs?keys=["1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c8736eab","181687d2f16debc10f9e365cc4002371"]
```

Response:

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "rows": [{
    "id": "1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c8736eab",
    "key": "1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c8736eab",
    "value": {
      "rev": "1-a26b67f478e4f3f8fd49779a66fc7949"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "181687d2f16debc10f9e365cc4002371",
    "key": "181687d2f16debc10f9e365cc4002371",
    "value": {
      "rev": "1-7338901ca1c5c06ef81a6971aa6e8f9d"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: You've already got `id` and `rev`.

Comment: I want `field_name` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The index of _all_docs does not contain the `field_name` data.
The only way to get it using this view is with `include_docs`.

Otherwise you will have to write (and index) your own view that emits what you want.

```js
map: function(doc) {
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc._id, _rev: doc._rev, field_name: doc.field_name });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using include_docs or manually populating all fields is to emit docs as values in a view, like that:

```
emit(doc._id, doc);
```

Comment: Quoting the documentation: "It is not recommended to emit the document itself in the view. Instead, to include the bodies of the documents when requesting the view, request the view with ?include_docs=true."